# My dialog control does not update my xpage

Tags: xpages-extlib

I try to update items via a dialog control. 
But my control OK button (or any other function in the dialog) do not refresh my "underlying" xpage. 
I^m sure it's sth quite simple ....

the (symplified example) code of the dialog:

```
<xe:dialog id="diaSnippet" title="Update my xpage" extractContent="true" 
preload="true">
    <xe:dialogContent id="dialogContent1">
        <xp:panel>
            <xp:inputText value="#{test.dialog1}" id="inputText1">
                <xp:this.defaultValue><![CDATA[#{javascript:test.getItemValueString("item1")}]]></xp:this.defaultValue>
            </xp:inputText>
        </xp:panel>
    </xe:dialogContent>
    <xe:dialogButtonBar id="dialogButtonBar1">
        <xp:panel>
            <xp:button id="button3" value="OK">

            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                refreshMode="complete">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:test.replaceItemValue("item1","1234")
getComponent("diaSnippet").hide()}]]></xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
        </xp:panel>
    </xe:dialogButtonBar>
</xe:dialog>
```

in my understanding the Ok should update the xpage, and should change the value of the item "item1", but it does nothing. 
thx in advance for any help, Uwe

Answer (score 1):

argh .... now I found the answer in the wiki:
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=Domino+Designer+XPages+Extension+Library#action=openDocument&res_title=Modal_dialogs_ddxl853&content=pdcontent

The settings in the "Server Options" on the event tab seem to do nothing, but writing the ID(s) to be refreshed in the hide() method does the trick. 
So instead of getComponent("diaSnippet").hide() I write getComponent("diaSnippet").hide("IDtorefresh)

Uwe